# Remote Silent install of Office 2013 returning 1603 error

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2013

Currently trying to install Office 2013 over Office 2010 on Windows 7 VMs across the network the batch file is the prescribed batch file given by Microsoft that uses OCT and using the latest download directly from the MS site.  Currently I have a method that works when I am logged in even if the install was triggered from a remote server by a different account.  If no one is logged in the method returns the following error:

> 2015/09/16 09:26:23:749::[2356] MSI(COMMONDATA): 'Message type:  1, Argument:  Microsoft InfoPath MUI (English) 2013'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:749::[2356] MSI(ACTIONSTART): 'Action 9:26:23: AllocateRegistrySpace. Allocating registry space'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:749::[2356] MSI(ACTIONSTART): 'Action 9:26:23: CA_RollbackTempHxDs. '
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:749::[2356] MSI(ACTIONSTART): 'Action 9:26:23: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:781::[2356] MSI(ACTIONSTART): 'Action 9:26:23: CA_RollbackHelpTransaction. '
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:781::[2356] MSI(ACTIONSTART): 'Action 9:26:23: RemoveODBC. Removing ODBC components'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:781::[2356] MSI(ACTIONSTART): 'Action 9:26:23: CA_BeginHelpTransaction. '
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:859::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Status: LANGID: 1033'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:859::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Entry: BeginTransaction started'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:859::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Error: BeginTransaction()->Could not set Registration session {90150000-0044-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:859::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Exit: BeginTransaction ended'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:859::[2356] MSI(INFO): 'CustomAction CA_BeginHelpTransaction returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:874::[2356] MSI(INFO): 'Action ended 9:26:23: InstallExecute. Return value 3.'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:874::[2356] MSI(COMMONDATA): 'Message type:  2, Argument:  0'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:874::[2356] MSI(COMMONDATA): 'Message type:  2, Argument:  0'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:874::[2356] MSI(COMMONDATA): 'Message type:  0, Argument:  1033'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:874::[2356] MSI(COMMONDATA): 'Message type:  1, Argument:  Microsoft InfoPath MUI (English) 2013'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:890::[2356] MSI(ACTIONSTART): 'Action 9:26:23: Rollback. Rolling back action:'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:937::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Status: LANGID: 1033'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:937::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Entry: RollbackTransaction started'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:937::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Status: RollbackTransaction()->Registration session not open'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:937::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Status: RollbackTransaction()->Ignored request to rollback'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:937::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Exit: RollbackTransaction ended'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:984::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Status: LANGID: 1033'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:984::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Entry: RemoveTempHxDs started'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:999::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Status: LANGID: 1033'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:999::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Entry: RemoveTempHxDsInternal started'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:999::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Status: LANGID: 1033'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:999::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Entry: CMsHelpObject constructor'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:999::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Status: RemoveTempHxDsInternal()->Removed temp hxds binary'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:999::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Exit: RemoveTempHxDsIntertnal ended'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:999::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Exit: CMsHelpObject destructor'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:999::[2356] MSI(INFO): '09/16/15 09:26:23 DDSet_Exit: RemoveTempHxDs ended'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:23:999::[2356] MSI(INFO): 'CustomAction CA_RollbackTempHxDs returned actual error code 1603 but will be translated to success due to continue marking'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:24:015::[2356] MSI(COMMONDATA): 'Message type:  2, Argument:  1'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:24:015::[2356] MSI(COMMONDATA): 'Message type:  2, Argument:  1'
>   2015/09/16 09:26:24:031::[2356] MSI(INFO): 'Action ended 9:26:24: INSTALL. Return value 3.'

I have tried using GPO, Task Scheduler is active, uninstalling Office 2010, removed HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags, various levels of permissions on the activating account.  The only thing that seems to work is being logged into the VM while the batch file is run.  This is a less than optimal method of installing a program over 250 times.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Further troubleshooting I have found that if I kill the svchost.exe process that controls the group of netsvcs services right before installing it will work.  If I wait the svchost starts again and it will fail.  Now the trick is to figure out how to kill that specific process just before attempting the install without knowing the PID for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the breakthrough I needed.  Running the following script and waiting 90 seconds before executing the install script does the trick:

```
        PSEXEC.EXE @C:\scripts\OfficeScripts\Office2013\ittest.txt -n 10 -h taskkill /F /IM svchost.exe /FI "SERVICES eq wuauserv"
```

Not 100% sure which service specifically is holding things up but this will allow the program to be installed.  A couple of points to note are it rests some of the remote ability so the install cmd file will not be able to run right a way.  This is why the 90 second delay in the second script running.  And the other note is waiting too long will have this scvhost.exe completely active again and will prevent the instillation.